# How to call from parent component child function in react, typescript and redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have child component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

class Child extends Component<any, any> {

    childFunction = () => {
        console.log('childFunction');
    };

    render() {
        return <div>Child</div>
    }
}

export default connect<any, any>(
    null,
    null
)(Child);


and parent component:

import * as React from "react";
import {Component, MouseEvent} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import Child from "./Child";

class Parent extends Component<any, any> {

    parentFunction = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        console.log("parent");
        //TODO : call child function?
    };

    render() {

        let child = <Child />;

        return <div>
            {child}
            <button onClick={(e) => this.parentFunction(e)}>Call child function from parent</button>

        </div>
    }
}

export default connect<any, any>(
    null,
    null,
    null,
    {forwardRef: true}
)(Parent);
```

The question is: how to call Child.childFunction() when click on button, which is in Parent component?

I have tried to create reference on Child: `React.createRef<Ref<Child>>();`, but get error: Error:(13, 39) TS2749: 'Child' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

The reason is: connect function in Child component.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to pass a function reference to the parent component. I'd caution against this, though; it'll get confusing quickly.

Comment: Why do you *want* to do this? It's somewhat counter to how things work. What survive problem are you trying to solve? Unrelated, but why do you use an arrow function in the onCkick property? Seems redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the function in your parent component called `parentFunction`

And in your `render` method of the parent component, give the property `parentFunction` to the child component, which will be refering to the parent component's function like `this.parentFunction`.

```
render(){
  return (
    <ChildComponent parentFunction={this.parentFunction} />
  )
}
```

Inside your child component, on the function that handles the button click, you will be able to access and invoke the function `parentFunction` which is sent from the parent as follows:

supposing that `childFunction` is the function you handle the button click with:

```
childFunction = (e) => { //don't forget to include the event to your onclick event handler
  console.log('childFunction');
  this.props.parentFunction(e); //the function invoked after being passed from parent component as a prop.
};
```

To read more about this, [Passing Data Between React Component](https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17).

Comment: Child component does not have any buttons.